# Left speaker produces a "hum/buzzing" sound when the computer is off

Tags: windows-10, audio, motherboard, speakers

I've been using this setup for 7 months, and I haven't had a problem with it so far until this morning.

I turned on my speakers (Edifier R1280T) as per routine, and I noticed the left speaker was making a humming/buzzing sound. I had thought that the speaker had given out, but the sound disappeared as soon as the computer turned on.

The speakers are working fine -- no change in audio quality or any distortions. It's just this weird gimmick that whenever the computer is off, the left speaker picks up on some sort of interference.

I did a quick test and turned on the speakers while disconnected from the computer, and they make no sound at all, so I assume the issue is with the computer and not the speakers.

I restarted the computer and found out that the sound stayed on until it finished loading through the Windows 10 start-up screen (black screen with spinning circles). So the speaker doesn't stop making the sound when the computer is "on" per se, but until it has booted up completely?

I have a Gigabyte GA-H97-D3H motherboard if that happens to help anyone.

I haven't changed any of the wirings or placed any devices nearby my computer that could cause interference.

Any suggestions to what could be the cause?

Comment: First suspect; computer PSU has some leak to ground issue that disappears once the audio circuit becomes active. I doubt it's 'fixable' in simple terms. Only test I can think of is to switch puter off, wait til it makes the noise, then unplug the puter from the mains, see if it goes away. Checking your mains is properly earthed might help, if you live in a country with compulsory earthing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed a suggestion of turning the computer off and disconnecting it from the power to see if the sound was still there. To my surprise, the sound got significantly louder.

I should've mentioned this before, but the way I have my audio setup is that I have my headphones and speakers connected to my computer via audio splitter (the motherboard only has one rear audio port for stereo).

So after the PSU test, I decided to check if it was by some means the headphones cable.

It was the headphones cable.

It turns out that the headphone jack was making contact with my desk. I usually have the cable nicely bundled up to the side when not in use, but I guess I left the jack pointing down instead of up this time or I accidentally moved it without noticing. Raising it away from the desk reduced the sound, but it took me touching the jack with my finger to remove the sound entirely--maybe it developed a static charge over time.

**Edit 1:** To clarify my poor wording: the sound disappeared *after* touching the headphone jack. It seems that this has solved the problem.

Comment: If touching it stops the noise, you definitely have an earthing problem - you become earth, noise goes away.